# why does fork program printf execute more time

Tags: c, linux, process, fork

from the [man page of fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) i read fork create duplicate of parent process. But not able to understand why below program `printf` execute **8** times. I read [Working of fork() in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513242/working-of-fork-in-linux-gcc) link also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    printf("process\n");
}
```

Comment: Because `2*2*2 == 8`.

Comment: I think you're forgetting that (some of) the children themselves are going to fork().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general for `n` `forks` in this manner will execute the next statements (in this case `printf`) `2^n` times.
Here is how:

```
|
+-fork()----------------------------------+
|                                         |
+-fork()-------------+                    +-fork()-------------+
|                    |                    |                    |
+-fork()---+         +-fork()---+         +-fork()---+         +-fork()---+
|          |         |          |         |          |         |          |
print()    print()   print()    print()   print()    print()   print()    print()
```

Answer (score 3):

Fork works like a binary tree. So its always 2^x number of processes on every x number of fork calls.

Lets understand with your example.

**First fork() call:**

When the first `fork()` is called. The parent process creates a new process. So we have 2 
threads.

**Second fork() call:**

At this point we have two processes(main process and a new created process).These two threads will call second fork individually and create 2 new processes each. so we have 4 threads.

You might have got the idea by now. Every time a fork() is encountered all the processes create their respective child processes(double themselves).

[image]

Comment: -1.  Lifted from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8768918/2235132) answer without attribution.

Comment: Sir, I haven't. I know it works like binary tree and I was providing a distinct explanation according to OP's question. And the image is the first result in google image search for `fork binary tree` FYI. Kindly do not down vote in such abrupt manner.

Comment: Fair enough; downvote reversed.